# $d$-dimensional Debye model: nonlinear dispersion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, dispersion

Given $\omega_k = c|k|^j$, where $j$ is some positive real number. I am attempting to compute the density of states $g(\omega) = \sum\limits_k \delta(\omega - \omega_k)$.

Given one can write the sum as $V/(2\pi)^d\Omega_d \int dk k^{(d-1)}\delta(\omega - c|k|^j)$.

I have no issues solving this for $\omega = ck$, but struggle when the dispersion is nonlinear. Am I missing something?